# Azure SQL - would Geo-replication cause any performance impact?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, geo-replication

I have an Azure SQL in WEST US and I want to setup the failover grop with EAST US.

would Azure SQL Geo-replication/failover group cause any performance impact? If so, what would be the impact?

Comment: No, not really.  The system reserves capacity to do that in the background so you should not notice impact in the general case

Answer (score 1):

Talking about the impact
In case of failure,
There might be 2 scenarios : Planned Failure and Unplanned Failure.

For Planned Failure,
Your primary database i.e. WEST US will first synchronize with secondary database i.e. EAST US. Then the EAST US db will become primary. This will prevent data loss.

For Unplanned Failure,
The secondary db EAST US will immediately takeover as primary db. Data Loss might happen depending on previous synchronization time.

There will be a performance impact in both the cases. Latency will increase. Microsoft has defined some best practices to minimize this impact.
Refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auto-failover-group-overview?tabs=azure-powershell#failover-groups-and-network-security

Comment: Thank you, Vikram Dhanwani. I want to know the performance impact on the primary SQL server due to enabling the Geo-Replication as it has to take care of the Replication as well.